# angular module is not defined when writing in coffescript

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, angularjs-scope

I have defined a angular app module as below

```
var dashboardApp = angular.module('dashboardApp', []);
```

It works fine, but when I rewrite this module in coffeescript, angular report a error

> > dashboardApp is not defined

The coffeescript code is :

```
dashboardApp = angular.module 'dashboardApp', []
```

I know the when wring in coffeescript, all variable is automatically wrapped to avoid polluting global scope.

So the question is: Does this mean angular require module to be defined in global scope? is it possible to use coffeescript to define the module?

#### Update

The accurate error message is

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: dashboardApp is not defined
```

I got this error because I use dashboardApp to create controller and service like this in other files:

```
dashboardApp.factory 'Utility', ->
Utility = {}
Utility.imageValidator = (file, max_size,allowed_type) ->
    file_type = file.type
    file_size = file.size
    result = true
    result = false if file_size > max_size
    result = false if ( allowed_type.indexOf(file_type) is -1)
    result

Utility
```

Comment: More information is needed to answer this. The error for angular not being able to find a module is more like 'module dashboardApp is not available'. What you've posted is more like a JavaScript error. Are you sure you're not trying to reference dashboardApp somewhere else you're expecting it to be in global scope?

Comment: I have updated the question with more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're experiencing is a JavaScript error, not an Angular one. You have a couple options.

- Use the module dependency pattern
- Combine the files
- Explicitly put dashboardApp in global scope

I suggest the module dependency pattern as it explicitly shows what modules depend on what other functionality.

#### App File

```
dashboardApp = angular.module 'dashboardApp', ['dashboardApp.factories']
```

#### Factory File

```
dashboardAppFactories = angular.module 'dashboardAppFactories, []
dashboardAppFactories.factory 'Utility' , => ...
```

Comment: I think the module dependency pattern is the one I am looking for. thanks